# Trouble with ShieldUI Line Graph Example - Binding to Local Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, linegraph, shieldui

I am trying to follow the example [Line Chart / Binding to Local Data](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/line-chart/local-data). I want to use a view model as my data source. In the view it expects a static method `GetElectricityPrices()`. How can I make it work with a non-static method?

Here is the view model:

```
public class ElectricityPrices
{
    public int YearPeriod { set; get; }
    public double PriceHousehold { set; get; }
    public double PriceIndustry { set; get; }
}
```

Here is the code that is in the view.

```
@(Html.ShieldChart(<ProjectName>.Controllers.<NameController>.GetElectricityPrices())
.Name("chart")
.Theme("light")
...
```

Here is a sample static method in the Controller.

```
public static ElectricityPrices[] GetElectrictyPrices()
{
    ElectricityPrices[] prices =
    {
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2001, PriceHousehold = 0.164, PriceIndustry = 0.103 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2002, PriceHousehold = 0.173, PriceIndustry = 0.105 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2003, PriceHousehold = 0.184, PriceIndustry = 0.112 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2004, PriceHousehold = 0.167, PriceIndustry = 0.111 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2005, PriceHousehold = 0.177, PriceIndustry = 0.102 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2006, PriceHousehold = 0.189, PriceIndustry = 0.099 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2007, PriceHousehold = 0.18, PriceIndustry = 0.011 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2008, PriceHousehold = 0.183, PriceIndustry = 0.113 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2009, PriceHousehold = 0.188, PriceIndustry = 0.117 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2010, PriceHousehold = 0.16, PriceIndustry = 0.119 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2011, PriceHousehold = 0.176, PriceIndustry = 0.123 },
        new ElectricityPrices { YearPeriod = 2012, PriceHousehold = 0.178, PriceIndustry = 0.117 },
    };
return prices;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the `GetElectrictyPrices()` function is `IEnumerable<ElectricityPrices>`.

The `Html.ShieldChart()` constructor can accept an `IEnumerable` collection of any type, which allows you to make a mapping using the `.Data(...)` method for each series you define to the chart.